# Content Editor Web Part - How to hide another CEWP for admins only

Tags: 2013

I am trying to hide elements on the page for viewer. I use a CEWP with this code:
https://pastebin.com/agwWTHFX

I use audience targetting for this part for "Everyone".

I then have another CEWP with this code:
https://pastebin.com/nQUWF7wy

This is targetted for admins. The point is everything hides for everyone, but people in the admin group see everything as normal.

The issue I am running into is that the CEWP which us supposed to hide the web part doesn't stop its CSS from working. So basically, it does nothing. Everything is hidden for everyone and admins.

Any ideas around this?